# Passing data using Handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, html, json, handlebars.js

I've created a basic app to test out handlebars.js and I'm struggling to pass data between my pages. What I want is to have a list of countries being read from a JSON file, then the user can click on a country to be taken to more detail. The data loads fine on the first page but then when I click onto the link, it takes me to the next page were the data isn't loading in.

Could someone explain where I'm going wrong?

**First page:**

```
  <div data-page="countrylist" class="page">
    <div class="page-content">
      <div class="content-block-title">Choose a country:</div>
      <div class="list-block">
        <ul>
          {{#each this}}
          <li>
            <a href="detail.html" class="item-content item-link" data-context-name="countrylist.{{@index}}​">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">{{Country}}​</div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          {{/each}}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Detailed page:**

```
<div data-page="countrylist" class="page">
    <div class="page-content">
      <div class="content-block inset">
        <div class="content-block-inner">
          <h3>{{Country}}​</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>Region: {{Region}}</li>
            <li>Population: {{Population}}</li>
            <li>Area Sq. Mile: {{AreaSqMile}}</li>
            <li>Population Density per sq. Mile: {{PopulationDensity}}</li>
            <li>NetMigration: {{NetMigration}}</li>
            <li>GDP $ per capita: {{GDP}}</li>
            <li>Phones per 1000: {{Phones}}</li>
            <li>Arable %: {{Arable}}</li>
            <li>Climate: {{Climate}}</li>
            <li>Birthrate: {{Birthrate}}</li>
            <li>Deathrate: {{Deathrate}}</li>
            <li>Agriculture: {{Agriculture}}</li>
            <li>Industry: {{Industry}}</li>
            <li>Service: {{Service}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
Template7.registerHelper('json_stringify', function (context) {
  return JSON.stringify(context);
});

var myApp = new Framework7({
  animateNavBackIcon: true,
  // Enable templates auto precompilation
  precompileTemplates: true,
  // Enabled pages rendering using Template7
  template7Pages: true
  // Specify Template7 data for pages
});

// Export selectors engine
var $$ = Dom7;

function getCountries() {
  $$.getJSON('../countries.json', function (json) {
    myApp.template7Data.countrylist = json ;
  });
};

getCountries();

// Add main View
var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main', {
  // Enable dynamic Navbar
  dynamicNavbar: true,
});
```

Comment: I don't see any router set up, so I'm guessing that your link to detail.html is navigating to a separate page and losing the context. Try setting up a router, otherwise you'll have to have separate code on the detail page to pull it's own data, which would be less efficient. Also, your question seems to have more to do with Template7 and not neccessarily handlebars.